# Push to new ViewController from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios

Is it possible to push to a new view controller from `ConnectionDidFinishLoading` ?

I have the following and it performs the `ConnectionDidFinishLoading` but does not push to new view controller.

```
-(void)connectionWithURLString:(NSMutableArray *)urlString
{
    NSDate *now =  [NSDate date];
    int userID = [[clientDataStruct.clientData objectForKey:@"number"] intValue];
    NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
  // NSLog(@"obj: %@", urlString);

    NSString *extrString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@", customerdetails:{customer_id = %d, job_date = %@, date_created = %@}",userID,date, now];

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=quote:{%@%@}", urlString, extrString ];

     NSLog(@"post: %@", post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *value = [defaults objectForKey:@"value"];

    NSString *jsonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxx?task=add_quote&user_id=%@&customer_id=%@",value, [clientDataStruct.clientData valueForKey:@"number"]];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonUrl]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



    if (!connection)
        NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
}

- (void)Success
{

        UIStoryboard *subVc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UserTableView *userTable = [subVc instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserTableView"];

        userTable.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:userTable animated:YES];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Success) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading%@", connection);
}
```

Everything works, and returns my data and data gets added into the `SQL`. My `NSLog` shows that `ConnectionDidFinishLoading`. But it does not push to the new View Controller.

Thanks for the help, being scratching my head on this one.

Thanks to Fahim advise allowed me to debug further, The Navigation view broke with a returned model controller. Changed it to push and all is working

Comment: Are you sure your `ViewController` is in a `NavigationController`?

Comment: you don't have navigation controller then... this works with navigation controller only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Point 1

This is not working with you because you don't have navigation controller. Make sure that you have navigation controller.

### Point 2

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoginSuccess) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading%@", connection);
}
```

This is something wrong. Even if user have entered incorrect username or password, you are still allowing user to get logged in.

Check the response that you are getting in connectionDidFinishLoading and then based on this response do the transition.

e.g. if you have PHP at backend your code will be

```
sql query here to add data

if (data added) {
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

now check this response in connectionDidFinishLoading and based on this do the transition

Comment: Hi Fahim, thanks for that. I edited my post to just change the name of the function. its not a login script so regardless of the response i wanted it to push to a new controller. Sorry about the confusion. Point 1, it is linked to the navigation controller on load. but i think it might not be after i add the objects from another controller. So im going to check that quick.

Comment: @SnakeBlisken : see my updated answer... if its not login, you should check whether data is added or not

Comment: I think you might be right about the Nav, although it is added, i think its being killed somewhere else. But this is a good start for me to debug further. I will revert with my findings. I'm going to however give this a Up vote, for its given me some ideas to debug further. Thanks

Comment: navigation controller was on load but ended up broken because the adding of objects returned with  model instead of push. All working. But in theory you where right!

Answer (score 0):

First check that if your LoginSuccess is getting called if yes then paste this

```
UserTableView * userTable =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserTableView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:userTable animated:YES]
```

like this [image: storyboard id] but replace ResultsTableView with UserTableView

Comment: Hi Sarfaraz, Yes it is. 2013-08-21 08:59:32.912 Site[20711:c07] Login Success

Comment: No its not. I think Fahim gave me a idea just to check the Navigation Controller. But on load it is linked to the navigation controller

Comment: Ok in the storyboard did u checkmarked Use storyboard id and wrote UserTableView in Storyboard ID field

Comment: Note your identifier and storyboard id should be same i.e instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserTableView"

Comment: Hi Sarfaraz, thanks for the comment. I'll try that. But i think its already added.